# Create table sql in Oracle which prompts for table name

Tags: sql, oracle, variables

I want to create table so that when the query runs, it asks for the table name. I am sure this is a duplicate post but would like to know if this is possible with Oracle?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using SQL*Plus, you can use substitution variables (&variable_name)

```
SQL> create table &name (
  2    col1 number,
  3    col2 date
  4  );
Enter value for name: fuzzy_bunny
old   1: create table &name (
new   1: create table fuzzy_bunny (

Table created.

SQL> select * from fuzzy_bunny;

no rows selected
```